# Create single.php for specific tag by tag id or name

Tags: php, wordpress

i have multiple tags and want to create multiple single.php for everyone tag.

**How create single.php for tags??**

> This code working well for category, how to edit it for tags??

```
 function my_category_templates($single_template) {
 global $post;

 if ( in_category( 'raspee' )) {
    $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/single-raspee.php';
 }
  return $single_template;
 }
 add_filter( "single_template", "my_category_templates" );
```

Comment: post your questions there http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You should learn about [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#tag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for tag with `has_tag()` function...

```
if ( has_tag( 'awesome' )) {
    $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/single-awesome.php';
}
```

You entire code will look like this...

```
function my_category_templates($single_template) {
global $post;

  if ( in_category( 'raspee' )) {
    $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/single-raspee.php';
  } else if ( has_tag( 'awesome' )) {
    $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/single-awesome.php';
  }
  return $single_template;
}
 add_filter( "single_template", "my_category_templates" );
```

We added `else if` to test for tag it only if first condition is not met, feel free to use `if` again if you have to...
Hope that helps.